# Kotlin - Add items to ExpandableListView

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to dynamically populate my expandable list view inside of Android Studio using Kotlin. But as of now, I wasn't able to find any up to date function to do so, all functions I found seem to be outdated. This is my skeleton code:

```
private val shows = listOf("First", "Breaking Bad", "Game of Thrones", "Bob and Martin...")

    private val expandableListView: ExpandableListView by bind(R.id.theListView)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //Add items to expandable list view here
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Google "ExpandableListView example" and you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: yep, I found the setAdapter function. Only seem to struggle creating an ExpandableListAdapter. I only managed to get an ArrayAdapter working, which doesn't help me much.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked fine.
In your activity where you define your listdata do this:

```
private ArrayList<HeaderInfo> SectionList = new ArrayList<>();
...
//create the adapter by passing your ArrayList data
listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(MyListActivity.this, SectionList);
//attach the adapter to the list
expandableListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

This is the constructor in my expandable list adapter

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<HeaderInfo> SectionList;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HeaderInfo>
SectionList) {   
    this.context = context;
    this.SectionList = SectionList;
}
...
```